# preventing transmission-daemon from auto start?

Tags: xubuntu, autostart, transmission

On Xubuntu 14.04 I have installed the package transmission-daemon. It appears to start automatically when I start the computer. Is it possible to prevent this from happening and instead I would like to start it manually.

additionally if I would like to restore it to autostart sometime in future, please advise how to do that as well..

Thanks,

Edit : 
Useful link to restore it again
[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-enable-transmission-daemon-start-at-startup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check /etc/default/transmission-daemon config file.

In it, set `ENABLE_DAEMON=0`, and it won't autostart.

Comment: Thanks, additionally can you tell me what relation does it have with file here  /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon ??

Comment: Just another config file.

Answer (score 10):

On newer versions using systemd it is a bit different.
Check if it is enabled with:
`systemctl status transmission-daemon.service`
Which will return something like:

`transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled;`

The **enabled;** means it will start on boot. To stop from starting on boot run:
`sudo systemctl disable transmission-daemon.service`

Now check the status again:

`transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; disabled;`

It should now be **disabled;**